# preg_replace() doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am currently trying to change a variable in a configuration file. I've tried the following:

```
public static function change(){
    $fl = file("../config.inc.php");
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $secret = $_POST['secret'];
    $content = "";
    foreach($fl as $line){
        $content .= $line;
    }
    $content = preg_replace("\$licence = array\(\'key\'=>\'(.*?)\'\);$", "licence = array('key'=>'$key');", $content);

    $content = preg_replace("/\$rey_connect = array\((.*?\'client_id\'=>\')(.*?)('.*?\'client_secret\'=>\')(.*?)(\')(.*?)(?:\));(?:\n|$)/", "\$rey_connect = array(\1$id\3$secret\5);", $content);

    $myfile = fopen("../config.inc.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "$content";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

on the following string:

```
<?php
# Bitte bearbeiten Sie diese Datei nicht. #

$mysql = array(  'host'=>'localhost',
                        'database'=>'schnnet',
                        'password'=>'root',
                        'user'=>'root');
$licence = array('key'=>'jZf5hhRd5vqmwTkMB9eq');
$rey_connect = array('active'=>true,'client_id'=>'123','client_secret'=>'123456');
?>
```

So the regex works perfectly [on phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/brC), but not in my script. Somehow it doesn't affect the configuration file's content.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain `$rey_connect = array('active'=>true,'client_id'=>'$id','client_secret'=>'$secret');`?

Comment: Yes, I try to change the client id and secret id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do you put your changes back to config?

> ```
> // this is really BAD approach
> $content = file_get_contents("config");
> $content = preg_replace(...);
> file_put_contents("config", $content);
> // or eval($content);
> ```

2. if you want to initiate reconnect to the database with slightly different parameter you can simply move your piece of code to separate function and call it with different parameter, e.g. you have script called utils.php

> ```
> function connect($host, $db, $pwd, $user, $key, $id, $secret)
> {
>     $mysql = array('host'=>$host,
>                    'database'=>$db,
>                    'password'=>$pwd,
>                    'user'=>$user);
>     $licence = array('key'=>$key);
>     $rey_connect = array('active'=>true,'client_id'=>$id,'client_secret'=>$secret);
> }
> ```

And then include utils.php into another script and call your function there.

```
include_once 'utils.php';

connect(
 'localhost', 
 'schnnet', 
 'root, 
 'root', 
 'jZf5hhRd5vqmwTkMB9eq', 
 '123', 
 '123456');
```

**UPDATE :**

I was able to reproduce issue that you described but have just ran simplified version of your code on my local server and it seems to be working as expected now. Try it.

```
<?php
    function change()
    {
        $id = 'someId';
        $key = 'someKey';
        $secret = 'someSecret';
        $content = file_get_contents("config.php");

        $content = preg_replace("/(licence[^>]+)([^)]+)(.+)/si", "$1>'" . $key . "'$3", $content);
        $content = preg_replace("/(client_id[^>]+)([^,]+)(.+)/si", "$1>'" . $id . "'$3", $content);
        $content = preg_replace("/(client_secret[^>]+)([^)]+)(.+)/si", "$1>'" . $secret . "'$3", $content);

        file_put_contents("config.php", $content);
    }

    change();
?>
```

Comment: I've edited my question with the full function, so I do put it back into the file.

Comment: @schn : 1. why do you need this regex at all, you do not have acccess to config file and cannot rewrite it as a function? 2. if you must work with regex only then add modifiers preg_replace(/.../gi, $content) to the end of your regex pattern, otherwise it will not work on multiline strings - http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added modifiers, but it still does not work. Here is a simplified [demo](http://ideone.com/YVNKzV)

Comment: @schn : what exactly does not work, did you check your config file, was it changed physically after execution of change() ? did you try to turn on display of all errors and warnings - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?  did you check log files on your server, do they have any errors mentioned?

Comment: The first regex works, so it changes the licence key, but the client id and client secret stay the same value. I have error reporting turned on, but neither on the page nor in the log files, errors are reported.

Comment: @schn : updated my answer with code example that works for me

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine: http://ideone.com/Gev03z

(Though you don't need the `'\'` before your replacement string.)

The problem is that you are not writing `$content` back to the file.

Changing `$content` only changes your local copy of what was in the file.

**EDIT:**

This is clearly not a regex issue, but a file permissions issue.

When you call [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) you do not check if the return is `false`. Which in this case I expect it is, meaning you cannot write to the file.

Now unless I miss my guess, it is because the file is already held open because `$fl`. Try adding a `close($fl);` prior to `$myfile`.

Comment: I've edited my question with the full function, so I do put it back into the file.

Comment: @schn This isn't exactly a regex issue then is it. I would suggest further edits to the question explaining that. In other news I've added a suggestion on how to fix your issue.

Comment: I don't think it is a permissions issure, because the licence key in the file is updated and fwrite does not return false, only the client id and client secret are not updated. Not even if I echo() it.

Comment: @schn And what happens when you print `$content` do you get the correct changes?

Comment: Not for client secret and client id

Comment: @JonathanMee : actually, he is right, there is definitely something wrong with his second regex, I was able to reproduce it, although I was to lazy to understand what exactly is wrong, so I completely rewrote his expression to shorter one